# Translate manipulate data Stata to R: if and recursive value in the same line

Tags: r, dplyr, stata

I am intermediate level in Stata and I feel comfortable working there. I always find the way to do the hardest tasks in Stata instead of R. However, I must present this one in R so I can not avoid it (even if Stata is always simpler to me) this time.

I want to translate this code:

```
gen new_variable = 0
replace new_variable = 1 if old_variable != old_variable[_n-1]
```

As per this website (https://www.matthieugomez.com/statar/manipulate-data.html), I should use *dplyr* library, specifically *ifelse* and *reduce* functions, which I do with the following code:

```
database$new_variable <- mutate(database$new_variable = ifelse(database$old_variable != Reduce(sum, database$old_variable, accumulate = TRUE), 1, database$new_variable))
```

However, it is not working. I know this code may be quite messy, but I'm so used to Stata.

The question is: How can I successfully translate that code from Stata to R with *dplyr* library? (if you have a simpler approach it would be great too).

Comment: @ totumin please create a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not the question but in Stata this is cleaner as one line: `gen new_variable = old_variable != old_variable[_n-1]`. If the data are time series, working with time series operators is better style. See also https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/

Comment: I guess one line will do the job: `dataframe$new_variable=ifelse(dataframe$oldvariable!=lag(oldvariable), 1,  0)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you give. Try this

```
library(dplyr)
new_var=0
database%>%
mutate(new_variable=ifelse(oldvariable!=lag(oldvariable),1,new_var)
```

Comment: Note that you should not use `database$` in `mutate()` calls.  Rather than `database$oldvariable` you should just use `oldvariable` otherwise things can get messed up for example if there are any grouping variables.